# how to show a video only from PC (responsive site) html/css

Tags: html, css

How can I display a video only if you are visiting my website with a PC with media queries? I just don't know how to setup the query in css or maybe it doesn't exist something like this. Can anyone help me?

The following is an example of a query that changes the body background of the site if your device is a mobile-phone.

```
  @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 700px) and (orientation : portrait) {
  body {
    background-image: url(http://objectfilms.altervista.org/background-mobile.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: absolute; 
    background-size:100%;
  }    
}
```

I need something like that but for a video instead of background, more or less like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1200px) {
  #video /* suppose the video has thid id */
    video:url (the url of the video)

}
```

Comment: Other programs like Javascript might be able to achieve that.

Comment: have you even tried using media queries with setting a condition to min-width of something? and then hit `display:none` in your video container? We can't help you with your code if we can't see one from your post.

Comment: I haven't posted any code because, as I said, I don't know how to setup the query. I just need a simple example, however I am editing the question to add some more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may try using media queries in css. This will be useful if your video is in foreground, not in background.

Resolution 1024 or above is used for PC/Desktop.

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {

  .videobox{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is the right tag (to avoid tablet-landscape being able to see the video)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) , screen and (max-height: 768px) { .video-div {display:none} }
```